# Version of driver installed with homebrew

Tags: sql-server, driver, homebrew

I have installed via homebrew the unixODBC driver manager and the FreeTDS driver in order to create a connection to a SQL server. 
Which is the brew command that can let me know which version of the driver has been installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the version and some information about any package with `brew info`. In your case, you can run:

```
brew info unixodbc
```

and

```
brew info freetds
```